# Ways to parse the EDI 834 formatted document with R?

Tags: r, edi

I am looking up for the way to parse the Insurance data which is present in the EDI 834 format. I know there are ways with JAVA and XML, but my requirement is to do it with R.

I have tried it with r and regex but as it contains elements and sub elements which i am unable to decode.

I am looking up for the to convert it into table with different columns containing values.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [free EDI API](https://www.edifabric.com/edi-api.html) and consume it just like any other REST API

Comment: Hi @JimA78 , Thanks for help, but i don't want to compromise the data by uploading  the file. Although it would be great if you can tell me how to do it with python or R.